# How to run handpose tfjs model in web worker

Tags: typescript, tensorflow, web-worker, tensorflow.js

I want to use webcamera to get frame and run tensorflow model "handpose" for estimating hand visibility. As we know, handpose model is a little slow so i try to move estimating to web worker.

the problem is `HTMLVideoElement object could not be cloned.` (I need to pass video to estimateHand method).

Is it possible to do it in another way?

web worker:

```js
import { getModel } from "../utils/tf-model";

let model: any;

const modelLoading = async () => {
    model = await getModel();
}

export const estimate = async (video: HTMLVideoElement) => {
    if (model) {
        const hands = await model.estimateHands(video);
        return hands;
    }
    return null;
}

modelLoading();

export default {} as typeof Worker & (new () => Worker);
```

main thread:

```js
import MyWorker from 'comlink-loader!./worker';

const worker = new MyWorker();

...

func = async () => {
        const res = await worker.estimate(this.video);
        ...
```

**EDIT**
I found the solution on my own, it's possible to get `ImageData` from canvas context and pass it to web worker.

```js
...
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// ofc we have to set width and height equal to video sizes ...

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.video.width, this.video.height);
const img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.video.width, this.video.height);
const res = await worker.estimate(img);
```

Comment: Could you explain your first line ```import { getModel } from "../utils/tf-model";```?
I'm currently using ```import * as handPoseDetection from '@tensorflow-models/hand-pose-detection';``` which doesn't work in a web worker. Where did you get tf-model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. It's so good that we can't pass HTML elements as parameters to web worker, but ofc we can play with canvas context as below:

```js
...
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// ofc we have to set width and height equal to video sizes ...

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.video.width, this.video.height);
const img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.video.width, this.video.height);
const res = await worker.estimate(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the video is not visible, the width and height might be empty so use videoWidth instead:

```js
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight

    const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    const img = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```